# Toggle Show / Hide Untoggle Click Outside

Tags: jquery, click, hide, toggle, show

**EDIT:** *I tried GLK.net's link but I could not manage to get this to work. It would simply break my function.*

I have a span element where, if you click it, it will toggle a ul (first click = show / second click = hide).

I want it so, if the ul is shown, the user should be able to click outside of the element (so, the document / html) to hide the list.

Here is my code:

btw, the $('hmtl').css('cursor', 'pointer'); is used for iOS.

(function($) {

```
$.fn.styledDropdown = function() {

    var obj = $('#tag-cloud');

    obj.find('.field').click(function() { // onclick event, show wp-tag

        if (obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud').is(':hidden')) {

            obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud').show();
            obj.find('i').attr('class', 'icon-eqtri-up');
            $('html').css('cursor', 'pointer');

            $(document).keyup(function(event) { // keypress event, hide wp-tag list

                if(event.keyCode == 27) {
                    obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud').hide();
                    obj.find('i').attr('class', 'icon-eqtri-down');
                    $('html').css('cursor', 'default');
                }

            });

        } else {

            obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud').hide();
            obj.find('i').attr('class', 'icon-eqtri-down');
            $('html').css('cursor', 'default');

        }

    });

    obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud li a').click(function() { // onclick event, change field value with selected list item and show list

        obj.find('.field').html( $(this).html() + '<i class="icon-eqtri-down"></i>' );
        obj.find('.wp-tag-cloud').hide();
        $('html').css('cursor', 'default');

    });

};
```

})(jQuery);

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

- Code has been adapted from an example at css-tricks.com